# How to change default unit in Paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

I'm using Paper.js (PaperScript) for engineering purposes, so I need all dimensions to be expressed in millimeters. Currently I'm using a conversion function:

```
function mm2px(mm){ return mm / 25.4 * 96 }
```

...but it would be nice to write everything in millimeters by default. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

There are no unit system in paparjs.
If you would like to use only mm unit, you can do it with `view.scaling = 96 / 25.4` in your conversion system.
Ref. http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#scaling.

Comment: This setting nicely produces objects with desired length (when I generate DXF outputs, they are accurate) but the drawing is exported to SVG, since there is no `mm` postfix in the dimensions, Inkscape interprets units wrongly.

Comment: I see :) Interesting feature. Probably, `for (var i = project.layers.length; i--; )project.layers[i].scaling = 96 / 25.4` would scale all elements in project.